# Set MakeMKV installed with snap to see optical drive

Tags: snap, dvd, mkv, optical, snap-store

Snap seemed to me the easiest way to [install MakeMKV](https://snapcraft.io/makemkv).

I ended up with a program that starts but doesn't react to the presence of a DVD. Trying to navigate manually to the drive, the `/media` folder is not seen.

[image]

I have heard about snap programs not seeing the system but I have imagined that could be by design, at least in some cases (a program might want to "see" just what it needs etc). But what's the purpose of a snap of MakeMKV that doesn't see the optical drive?

The Snapcraft page promotes the application in its normal use to "Backup your DVD and Bluray discs".

***How is it supposed to work?*** I mean, is this expected behavior? Is there a problem with this specific snap? Could [the flatpack version](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.makemkv.MakeMKV) work better?

This is in Kubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Snaps work in containers with a limited view of the base file-system (unless *classic* confinement is used), however you can `snap connect [snap]:removable-media` to enable access for snaps to common directories like `/media`, `/mnt`.. (by default they are limited to files located in $HOME for security reasons)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix Snap you have to connect the following Snap interfaces:

```
snap connect makemkv:optical-write
snap connect makemkv:removable-media
```

Nice way to fix it with 100% success is to use deb-package [from PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eheyarje/+archive/ubuntu/makemkv-beta?field.series_filter=focal). Install it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:heyarje/makemkv-beta
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install makemkv-bin
```

Comment: How can one make the tool have access to other locations, like `/media`, where other partitions are mounted (possibly containing source files and disk images)?